# Вложенность категорий в Битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Есть список товаров и категории к ним.Вложенность для всех товаров - 2 уровня.
То есть елементов,которые будут находиться на первом уровне,вообще не будет.

Схема: `/cat1/cat2/item-vzat.html`

Вопрос заключается в том,какого формата должен быть файл импорта `CSV`?(чтобы была указанная вложеность у товаров).

*Также были попытки.В результате,вложенность была,но адекватного результата ждать не пришлось.Основные категории импортировались все,а подкатегории для каждой основной - только по одной.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример первой строки в выгрузке:

```
IE_XML_ID;IE_NAME;IE_ID;IE_ACTIVE;IE_ACTIVE_FROM;IC_GROUP0;IC_GROUP1;IC_GROUP2
```

где:

`IC_GROUP0` — группа первого уровня в Вашем случае `cat1`

`IC_GROUP1` — группа первого уровня в Вашем случае `cat2`